# zoom on hover working in live preview; not on server

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found a zoom on hover snippet that is working in my Brackets Live Preview but not when I upload the page to my website.  I hope I have posted all the code I need to reproduce the problem.  When I hover over the image, nothing happens even though it works in Live Preview.  I appreciate any feedback on how to solve the problem.

```
#gallery {
    width: 300px;  
    height: 3600px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
#gallery p:nth-child(2n+4) {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
#centerHover {
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 0 1em 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;       
    }
h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    }
.img-zoom {
    width: 310px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5); 
    -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
    -o-transform: scale(2.5);
    transform: scale(2.5);
    }


<div id="gallery">
                <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
                <p id="centerHover">Center image vertically on page and hover to enlarge.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis's warrant to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River.  Robert Mosby &#40;among others&#41; was a witness.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17900212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="259" height="387"></p> 
                <p>Alexander Lewis's survey dated 12 Feb 1799 for the above warrant.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his 200 acre survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805.  Alexander's son Robert was a witness.  Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p>
            </div>

   <script src="jquery.js"></script>  

   <script>

       //THIS IS THE JS FROM THE DEMO

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
  });

       //THIS IS THE END OF THE JS FROM THE DEMO
</script>
```

Comment: Any time you are talking about javascript not working, you need to look at your browser's console and report any errors / notices that may be appearing.  Almost certainly that will identify the issue.

Comment: Can you check console and confirm if you see any errors..

Comment: thanks for your messages but I am very new to this and I have no idea what the browser console is.  This is the first I am hearing this term.  I did try Googling "check browser console for errors" but was left none the wiser.  It did say to open the page in another browser which I did and I am having the same problem in Firefox as Chrome.  How exactly do I check the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged jQuery with this but don't have any jQuery code added to your question.

Are you using jQuery for the hover effects? I know this sounds dumb, but I have personally made the mistake of having jQuery locally and not uploading the jQuery min file I was using to my server.

Comment: Karol, this is not the answer. You have to add this as a comment.

Comment: Not enough rep yet to comment apparently ;) 10 pts to go LOL

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I omitted the jQuery code. I pasted it into my example. So I need to upload the jquery.js file referenced in my line of code "<script src="jquery.js"></script>" - is that correct?

Comment: Oops sorry for that :P

Comment: Thank you Karol!  I added my jquery.js file to my server and all is well.  Much appreciated.

Comment: LOL no problem Barton! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use property

```
img-zoom:hover
```

instead of img-zoom

Check out this :

```css
#gallery {
    width: 300px;  
    height: 3600px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
#gallery p:nth-child(2n+4) {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
#centerHover {
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 0 1em 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;       
    }
h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    }
.img-zoom:hover {
    width: 310px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5); 
    -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
    -o-transform: scale(2.5);
    transform: scale(2.5);
    }
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
                <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
                <p id="centerHover">Center image vertically on page and hover to enlarge.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis's warrant to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River.  Robert Mosby &#40;among others&#41; was a witness.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17900212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="259" height="387"></p> 
                <p>Alexander Lewis's survey dated 12 Feb 1799 for the above warrant.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his 200 acre survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805.  Alexander's son Robert was a witness.  Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p>
            </div>
```

**Solution 2 :**

**By Using Jquery :**

```js
$('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');

    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
```

```css
#gallery {
    width: 300px;  
    height: 3600px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
#gallery p:nth-child(2n+4) {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
#centerHover {
    font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 0 1em 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;       
    }
h1 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FAA91D !important;
    }
.img-zoom {
    width: 310px;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
.transition {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5); 
    -moz-transform: scale(2.5);
    -o-transform: scale(2.5);
    transform: scale(2.5);
    transform-origin: 0% 40%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery">
                <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
                <p id="centerHover">Center image vertically on page and hover to enlarge.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis's warrant to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River.  Robert Mosby &#40;among others&#41; was a witness.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17900212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="259" height="387"></p> 
                <p>Alexander Lewis's survey dated 12 Feb 1799 for the above warrant.</p>
                <p><img class="img-zoom" src="http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="259" height="387"></p>
                <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his 200 acre survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805.  Alexander's son Robert was a witness.  Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p>
            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but that just results in the image expanding slightly left to right.  There should be an overall significant enlargement of the entire image (say 150%) when hovering.  That's how it was working in Live Preview.

Comment: means you have to enlarge image in whole page when hover.??

Comment: if I understand you correctly, yes.  You hover on the image and it enlarges uniformly on the page - to 1 1/2 or 2 times its smaller size or whatever.  The issue was that I had not loaded my jquery.js file to my server.  Now that I did it works great.